# Can anyone help interpret this ANOSIM result for a species composition between two sites?

Tags: r

I carried out an ANOSIM on my species composition data. I was looked at difference in species composition between two forest types. When I carried out my ANOSIM I got r = 0.13, p = 0.004. Is this significant or not?

Comment: It is significant as the p value is less than 0.05. It is significant at p <0.01.

Comment: First, since this question is about interpreting statistical output and not programming, I'm voting to move it to [stats.se]. Second, "is this significant?" is a question that really should be [asked in context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance#Role_in_statistical_hypothesis_testing) and depends on your alpha. You need to decide first what you consider "significant" to be

Comment: @BappaDas *if* they've defined alpha as 0.05, but that isn't said in the question